# s3api list-objects doesn't work when requester pay is enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Will `list-objects` work with requester pay enabled?

The following command worked without requester pay enabled.

```
aws --profile <profile> s3api list-objects --bucket <bucket-name>
```

But with requester pay enabled, I got an access denial error from the same command. When I added the option `--request-payer requester`, I got an option not recognized error.  For `get-object`, it worked as expected.

Did I do something wrong or simply list-objects won't work with requester pay enabled?

Comment: If that's a direct copy-paste, then `buckect` has a typo in it...

Comment: Thanks Ryan. It's a typo in the post and I've corrected it.